# Start Selenium Server with multiple Firefox profiles

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I can start Selenium Server with some profile:

```
java -jar C:\driver\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=MyFFProfile
```

But is it possible to somehow start Selenium Server with more named profiles, so I just chose it on code side?

Current code for usage of FF from Selenium Server:

```
browser = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
#browser = {'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': False, 'version': '', 'platform': 'ANY', 'javascriptEnabled': True}
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", browser)
```